# can anyone debug the result ? and explain the value of x

Tags: java, for-loop

what happen in `x=x++;` , i need explain why `x` after loop still 3 #

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=3;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            if(i==1) {
                x=x++;
            }
            if(i%2==0&&x%2==0) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            if(i%2==0&&x%2==1) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            if(i==2^x==4) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }

        }
            System.out.print("<");
    }
```

output: --,<

Comment: NEVER use a pre-/post-increment operator on a variable and use the variable a second time in the same expression.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `x++` means increment `x` by 1, but yield the original value of `x` (before the increment). In the statement `x = x++`, the `x++` part is executed first, yielding always 3. The assignment is executed after, assigning 3 to `x`, so that `x` never changes.

Answer (score 0):

x++ post-increment means first it will use x then increment e.g

```
x=0 // x is 0
array[x++] = 31 // after execution of this statement x is 1.
```

It will store 31 in the first index of array and then increment x.

Comment: the value of x didn't change after loop

Comment: Yes because x=x++ here x is assigned is 3 which will only run when i==1 , so it executes only one time in which 3 is again assigned to x.